# Font Override Issue

Tags: fonts

Morning

I am trying to change the font of paragraphs using either css or html.

If I do this in preview mode I can see the change happen, however on saving and publishing the text change does not appear.

Below is what I have been using

```
<p style="font-family:Indie Flower;">This is a paragraph.</p>
```

Or in CSS within the items

```
font-family: "Indie Flower", sans-serif;
```

After googling issues I found information about the important rule and when looking in the CSS I have found the below code.

```
body {
        font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif !important;
        color: #0f1e64;
    }
```

Would this be stopping me from changing the font type? If so how can i go about allowing the text change?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change to

`<p style="font-family:Indie Flower !important;">This is a paragraph.</p>`

This should override the other one.

Edit.. 
Or use classes

You could also use css classes

`<style>`
`.IndieFlower{`
`font-family:Indie Flower !important;`
`}`
`</style>`

`<p class="IndieFlower">This is a paragraph.</p>`

Comment: Thanks have applied but still not working must be another issue, I will continue to investigate.

Comment: That or use chrome then CTRL-Shift-I to inspect the html code and css. Will in most cases show you exactly what is overriding YOUR style.

Comment: So after much trouble shooting and following your instructions everything should have worked but for some reason it still wasn't. So i decided to try and use google fonts eg. @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Gloria+Hallelujah'). This works until i put other code in the css file (even unrelated), i have tried a range of other things even simply hiding a button but as soon as I add more code the font stops working, any thoughts on why?

Comment: It's a semicolon all that was needed so simply thanks for the help